# Database Migration doesn't work in sqlserver 2012

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

Database creation and migration works in sql 2008,but it does not work in sql2012.

Error : "Column 'IpAddress' in table 'ePoll.Answer' is of a type that is invalid 
for use as a key column in an index."

propery in model :

```
 [MaxLength(39)]
 [Index(IsClustered = false)]
 public string IpAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the migration?

Comment: Is it honoring the max length on the db side? Try without the index first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database migration works when i use [Required] attribute.

```
 [Required]
 [MaxLength(39)]
 [Index(IsClustered = false)]
 public string IpAddress { get; set; }
```